# How to setup mercurial subrepos to be cloned from both Windows and Linux

Tags: mercurial

I have the following repository structure on a Linux machine:

```
-- source_control
    -- projects
        project1
        project2
        ...
    -- repositories
        repo1
        repo2
        repo3
        ...
```

Meaning I have a `source_control` directory with two nested directories called `projects` and `repositories`. The `repositories` directory contains "simple" repos (i.e., repos that don't have subrepos) and `projects` contains repos that are just thin layers and contain subrepos from the `repositories` directory.

Right now my .hgsub files in various projects look something like this:

```
repo1 = /mnt/network/drive/source_control/repositories/repo1
repo2 = /mnt/network/drive/source_control/repositories/repo2
```

And so on. Now, since all the developers worked on linux machines where the same network drive was mounted, this worked perfectly. However, we now need to work from Windows as well. This causes some problems as the Windows machines can't access the subrepos path (the network drive IS accessible from the Windows machines, they just use a different path).

I tried changing the `.hgsub` file to:

```
repo1 = ../../repositories/repo1
repo2 = ../../repositories/repo2
```

But this doesn't work (when I commit the `.hgsub` file, the subrepos are empty).

I also tried serving the repositories in HTTP, but it slows things down considerably and I would like to find a better way (all the machines are in a local network).
What is the correct way to use relative paths in my `.hgsub` so I can work from both Windows and Linux machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository#Nested_repository_subpaths) wiki, the way to get this to work with a completely new repository would be:

```
$ echo repo1 = ../../repositories/repo1 > .hgsub
$ hg clone ../../repositories/repo1
; here you could update to whichever version you wanted
$ hg add .hgsub
$ hg commit -m "New relative subrepo added"
```

Then cloning the main repository also clones the sub-repository, as the path is relative.  It works from my Windows machine, so your idea is basically correct.

In your instance, I think that committing the modified `.hgsub` is clearing the directory because you have redefined what the subrepo points to (I have no idea if this behaviour is by design).  So perhaps before you commit you could delete the entire subdirectory yourself and re-clone:

```
; modify .hgsub as above
$ rm -rf repo1
$ hg clone ../../repositories/repo1
$ hg commit -m "Made repo1 relative"
```

Doing this may mean that people updating would need to pull down the entire subrepo again, or they may even need to re-clone the entire project, but after that it should "just work".

Of course, try it on a test project first, just to make sure :)